# ¿Que significa esta linea en html?

Tags: html

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Por un lado, tengo la siguiente linea:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
```

Entiendo que lang hace referencia al idioma, pero,  ¿El atributo dir a que hace referencia? ¿A la dirección de qué?

Por otro lado, tambien me llama la atencion la siguiente linea:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

¿A que hace referencia utf-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Buenas tardes:**
En tu ejemplo la etiqueta

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
```

- el attributo `lang` es para especificar el tipo de idioma que
  contendra el documento [declaracion de
  idiomas](https://cybmeta.com/el-atributo-lang-en-html)
- el attributo `dir` se usa para especificar al [orientacion del
  texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/dir)

**ejemplo:**

```html
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">
<p>soy un texto de derecha a izquierda!</p>
```

la etiqueta:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

- el attributo `charset="utf-8"` se utiliza para especificar la
  [codificacion de
  caracteres](https://cybmeta.com/meta-charset-como-y-por-que-utilizarlo-siempre)
  que contendra el documento

Comment: Curiosidad, hablando de la *izquierda*, ¿por qué el signo de admiración no aparece al lado de esa palabra?

Answer (score 3):

`lang` y `dir` son parte de lo que se conoce como *atributos globales* de los documentos HTML y XML, como indica el apartado [3.2.5. *Global attributes*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#global-attributes) de W3C Recommendation.

La definición oficial es esta:

> ### [`lang`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#the-lang-and-xmllang-attributes)
>
> El atributo `lang` (fuera de los espacios de nombres) especifica el
>   idioma principal para el contenido del elemento y para cualquiera de
>   los atributos del elemento que contienen texto. Su valor debe ser una
>   etiqueta de idioma [BCP 47](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/references.html#biblio-bcp47) válida, o una cadena vacía. Establecer
>   el atributo a cadena vacía indica que el idioma principal es
>   desconocido.

---

> ### [`dir`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#the-dir-attribute)
>
> El atributo `dir` especifica la direccionalidad del texto del
>   elemento. El atributo es un atributo enumerado con las siguientes
>   palabras clave y estados:
>
> - **La palabra clave `ltr`, que se asigna al estado *`ltr`***
>
>   Indica que los contenidos del elemento son texto de izquierda a derecha explícitamente aislado direccionalmente.
> - **La palabra clave `rtl`, que se asigna al estado *`rtl`***
>
>   Indica que los contenidos del elemento son texto de derecha a izquierda explícitamente aislado direccionalmente.
> - **La palabra clave `auto`, que se asigna al estado *`auto`***
>
>   Indica que los contenidos del elemento son explícitamente texto aislado direccionalmente, pero que la dirección se debe determinar
>     mediante el uso de los contenidos del elemento (como se describe a
>     continuación)<sup>1</sup>.

Cabe decir que `dir` se puede usar también a nivel de elementos particulares del documento, por ejemplo:

```html
<p dir="ltr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p dir="rtl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

---

En cuanto a la línea: `<meta charset="utf-8">` lo que hace es definir un atributo que pertenece al grupo *meta data content*, definido en el apartado [3.2.4.2.1. Metadata content de W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#metadata-content).

> El contenido de metadatos es contenido que configura la presentación o
>   el comportamiento del resto del contenido, o que establece la relación
>   del documento con otros documentos, o que transmite otra información
>   "fuera de banda".

Hay que tener cuidado de creer que todos los elementos de este grupo llevan etiqueta `meta`. No es así, `meta` es parte del grupo de elementos del tipo *meta content*, entre los cuales están también `base, link, title, script, style...`

Vamos entonces a definir `meta` en cuanto elemento y así completamos la respuesta:

> ### [`meta`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/document-metadata.html#elementdef-meta)
>
> El elemento `meta` representa varios tipos de metadatos que no pueden
>   expresarse utilizando los elementos `title`, `base`, `link`, `style`,
>   y `script` .
>
> El elemento `meta` puede representar metadatos a nivel de documento
>   con el atributo de nombre, directivas pragma con el atributo
>   `http-equiv` y la declaración de codificación de caracteres del
>   archivo cuando un documento HTML se serializa en forma de cadena (por
>   ejemplo, para la transmisión a través de la red o para el
>   almacenamiento en disco), con el atributo `charset`.
>
> #### [`charset`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/document-metadata.html#character-encoding-declaration)
>
> El atributo `charset` especifica la codificación de caracteres
>   utilizada por el documento. Esta es una [declaración de codificación
>   de caracteres](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/document-metadata.html#character-encoding-declaration). Si el atributo está presente en un documento XML,
>   su valor debe ser una coincidencia ASCII que no distinga entre
>   mayúsculas y minúsculas para la cadena "utf-8" (y, por lo tanto, el
>   documento está obligado a usar UTF-8 como su codificación).

Cabe decir que el atributo `charset` es importante para la presentación de páginas, sobre todo para el manejo de acentos y caracteres especiales. A veces, si este atributo no se maneja bien, aparece en el contenido los acentos sustituidos por otras caracteres extraños o por el caracter inspector.

---

1. Ver el apartado [3.2.5.5. The `dir` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#the-dir-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

La etiqueta:

-Lang:en=> exactamente hace referencia al ingles 
-dir=>ltr=>Significa izquierda a derecha y es usado para los lenguajes que son escritos de izquierda a derecha ( como el Inglés,español,portugués por ejemplo ) y en sentedido contrario se usa el rtl(por ejemplo como el arabe que va de derecha a izquierda)

-charset="utf-8"=>En HTML5 la codificación por defecto si no se especifica nada es UTF-8. No obstante, es el navegador el que finalmente decide la codificación a utilizar. Para evitar un visionado incorrecto en algunos navegadores o navegadores mal configurados, es recomendable incluir siempre la etiqueta meta charset.
Importante UTF-8 para visualizar ñ o tildes.